# Create a truth table for an algorithm

Tags: math, logic, truthtable

I'm a computer science undergrad and i was asked to create an algorithm then the corresponding truth table.

```
a =  ants are angry
b =  birds are busy
c =  cats are cool

If ants are angry, then birds are not busy. 
If cats are cool then birds are busy.
Cats are not cool. Therefore ants are angry.
```

This is it here, is it correct? Thanks for your help.

[image: mac word screenshot, ens1161]

Comment: You should review the truth table for [logical implication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_conditional). `x->y` is true if `x` is `false`, regardless of what `y` is.

Comment: "If ants are angry, then birds are not busy." -- what sort of crazy BS is this? Surely the instructor can create examples more meaningful than that!

Comment: @MattClarke are you sure,... while I was teaching it was a problem to generate different meaning full tasks for each student each semester for each class ... (for a while it is OK but after few years is hard to generate unique (not copies ...) problems suited for task , meaningful for praxis and with some sense ... )... for math you can do a smal variation and get new assigment but in programming a small variation leads to copy paste solutions which is not desirable ...